# Password less login in snowflake from pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, aws-glue, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am new to snowflake. I am creating an ETL job where we need to access the snowflake database.

I am trying to connect to snowflake from two places. One from the ec2 instance using a shell script and other from pyspark in aws glue. 
When I am trying to connect from a shell script, I am keeping my password in the config file and when I am trying to connect from pyspark, I have to give my password as below

sfOptions = {
  "sfURL" : 'xxx',
  "sfAccount" : 'xxx',
  "sfUser" : 'xxx',
  "sfPassword" : 'xxx',
  "sfDatabase" : 'xxx',
  "sfSchema" : 'xxx'
}

But I don't want to give a password like this as it is not safe. I want passwordless login or key pair authentication login from both shell script and pyspark. I did find one doc here 
https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/snowsql-start.html#using-key-pair-authentication

But I don't know whether it will work in pyspark and shell script. and if it works, then how to pass the password in sfOption shown above. Basically, I don't want to give "sfPassword" : 'xxx' in the above connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not store password in SSM to store credentials and use in glue?  Read
https://medium.com/nordcloud-engineering/ssm-parameter-store-for-keeping-secrets-in-a-structured-way-53a25d48166a for usage of ssm